# Allocation of task based on start date and end date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```py
dic= {'Test ID':'100001','100002','100003','100004','100005','100006','100007','100008','100009','100010','100011','100012','100013','100014','100015'],     
'Wanted start':['24W01','24W06','24W01','24W04','24W01','24W03','24W07','24W09','24W01','24W06','24W01','24W04','24W01','24W03','24W07'],
'Wanted completed':['24W05','22W10','24W03','22W10','24W02','24W06','24W08','24W10','24W05','22W11','24W03','24W10','24W02','22W06','24W10']
}
df= pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

Please help to get a solution for one tricky problem in Python.

`df` where the task needs to be allocated based on the start date and end date mentioned in the input data frame.`df` Input and Output Images for your reference.

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWj1L.png)

[Output look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVo9P.png)

Comment: Your question is too vague and lacks a [mre]

Comment: This question looks like several question in one, a code-request post omitting to show prior research effort. Have you been through [ask]? Besides, your expected output contains information that is absent from input: 'Car ID' and 'user'

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for pointing out the specific format of the start and end dates, which is in the year-week format like "24W01." To address this in Python, we can use the pd.to_datetime function with a custom format string.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your input data
dic = {'Test ID': ['100001', '100002', '100003', '100004', '100005', '100006', '100007', '100008', '100009', '100010', '100011', '100012', '100013', '100014', '100015'],
       'Wanted start': ['24W01', '24W06', '24W01', '24W04', '24W01', '24W03', '24W07', '24W09', '24W01', '24W06', '24W01', '24W04', '24W01', '24W03', '24W07'],
       'Wanted completed': ['24W05', '22W10', '24W03', '22W10', '24W02', '24W06', '24W08', '24W10', '24W05', '22W11', '24W03', '24W10', '24W02', '22W06', '24W10']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

# Convert start and end dates to datetime objects
df['Wanted start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Wanted start'] + '-1', format='%YW%W-%w')
df['Wanted completed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Wanted completed'] + '-1', format='%YW%W-%w')

# Create a new DataFrame to store the allocated tasks
allocated_tasks = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Test ID', 'Allocated start', 'Allocated completed'])

# Iterate through the rows of the original DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    allocated_start = row['Wanted start']
    allocated_completed = row['Wanted completed']
    
    allocated_tasks = allocated_tasks.append({
        'Test ID': row['Test ID'],
        'Allocated start': allocated_start,
        'Allocated completed': allocated_completed
    }, ignore_index=True)

# Print the allocated tasks DataFrame
print(allocated_tasks)
```

Comment: Please check the output image attached.